# how to click mp4 file link open browser when using vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperlink

When writing a `file:///mypath.mp4`  link in vscode then ctrl+leftcilk it will open in vscode, however, mp4 file seems to can't open. So I want to it open in browser or use other video software. The need come from every time I want to review courses will spend lots of time to look for the specific chapters. But I use `file:///mypath.mp4#=hh:mm:tt`to open a video file, it will very convenient.

Comment: Would the [`analytic-signal.preview-mp4`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=analytic-signal.preview-mp4) extension solve your problem? Or possibly [`mkloubert.vs-media-player`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vs-media-player) or [`sirkane.vscode-mediaplayer`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sirkane.vscode-mediaplayer)?

Comment: I don't want vscode to play mp4, but I hope it can open **file:///mypath.mp4** in the browser like opening **https://www.google.com** by pressing ctrl+left-click. I don't know if vscode can do this. If it can't, the recommended solution above is also a good option.